# Jenkins archival without parent directories

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins instance puts archived builds into zip files in sub-directories `archive\projects\<project name>\<build target>`. I'm currently using Windows and often use the built-in zip extration ('extract all' in the context menu), which makes it a hassle to extract archives stored this way.

Thus I'd prefer that those files would go directly into the zip file without those parent directories. Is it somehow possible? Or would that break some assumptions? The Project configuration on the Jenkins GUI does not offer such option, and so far google did not turn anything useful up either.

Comment: Since this is now officially declared as tumbleweed, and I haven't found any other solution, it appears to me as being impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because It has been quite a while now, and I have found a satisfiying solution, I will post a self-answer here.

What my solution was, is to create a installer .exe using NSIS (Nullsoft installation system) and make *this*, not the folder itself, an artifact.

- You get much more controll on what is downloaded / installed.
- The download is MUCH* faster, because the on-demand-zip is not created.

For a good tutorial, look [here](https://www.rolandbaer.ch/software/tutorials/nsis-tutorial-teil-1/).

*) Actually <2 sec vs 20 seconds for about 100megs of dll files.